# CSS background images not showing up

Tags: html, css, background-image

Why background image not showing up on page? I have unordered list which contained two background images list items.

```css
.grid {
  height: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.small {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.large {
  flex-basis: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="small" style="background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/spring-flowers-blue-crocuses-drops-water-backgro-background-tracks-rain-113784722.jpg);"></li>
  <li class="large" style="https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you seeing when inspecting the page?

Comment: Try to avoid the style attribute if you can. Some developers say its unorganised, and it's always good to have all your styles in one place. That way, if it doesn't work, you can quickly fix it, because the style attribute are more specific so they overwrite the other styles. Not so helpful for fixing errors.

Comment: the second <li style= in the html  is obviously wrong. It schould lookt like the first  [ e.g <li style="background-image: url(...); "].

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `background-image: url` to your second `li` for the code to register the URL.

```
<li class="large" style="background-image: URL(https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500);"></li>
```

Alternatively, I would recommend that you shift your `url` to your CSS file to make your HTML code neater and more readable.

```
.small {
  [other css]
  background-image: url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/spring-flowers-blue-crocuses-drops-water-backgro-background-tracks-rain-113784722.jpg");
}

.large {
  [other css]
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `background-image:url()` for the second list item.

```css
.grid {
  height: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.small {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.large {
  flex-basis: 70%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="small" style='background-image: url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/spring-flowers-blue-crocuses-drops-water-backgro-background-tracks-rain-113784722.jpg");'>
  </li>

  <li class="large" style='background-image:url("http://placekitten.com/301/301")';></li>
</ul>
```

> With code moved to css file:

```css
.grid {
  height: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.small {
  flex-basis: 30%;
  background-image: url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/spring-flowers-blue-crocuses-drops-water-backgro-background-tracks-rain-113784722.jpg");
}

.large {
  flex-basis: 70%;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/301/301");
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">
  <li class="small">
  </li>
  <li class="large"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

the URL of the image has to go under " " (quotations). Also, the 2nd item has some syntax errors.

```
 <li class="small" style="background-image: url("https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/spring-flowers-blue-crocuses-drops-water-backgro-background-tracks-rain-113784722.jpg");"></li>

<li class="large" style="background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/462118/pexels-photo-462118.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500");"></li>
```

Comment: I tried all the changes you guys suggested but only thing I can see on webpage is very thin line of images and not whole images.